# How do I refer to capture groups in a MySQL regex?

Tags: mysql, regex

How to reference to a group using a regex in MySQL?
I tried:

```
REGEXP '^(.)\1$'
```

but it does not work.
How to do this?

Comment: Post your complete query please.

Comment: I want know how do this, this is an only example.

SELECT * FROM table WHERE fields REGEXP '^test(.)\1$'

Comment: @The Mask: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: an example: 
on table: 
foo  foo 
ab   aa 

I need extract 'aa' but the values are variables.

an example as this works in javascript:

var str = "aa bd ed"; 
var result = str.match(/(.)\1/); //aa,a

Comment: When you clarify a question, please edit the question rather than posting comments.  All else apart, you get a lot more formatting power in a question than you do in a comment.

Comment: It makes no sense to use capturing groups in REGEXP as done in this example. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can't, there is no way to reference regex capturing groups in MySql.

Comment: +1 Good answer. They say "Back references are a dreadful botch, posing major problems for efficient implementations. They are also somewhat vaguely defined (does 'a\(\(b\)*\2\)*d' match 'abbbd'?). Avoid using them." at http://linux.die.net/man/7/regex so I gather the lack of the back reference feature is a bug.

Comment: @d5e5 did you mean that the bug is a feature?

Answer (score 84):

(Old question, but top search result)

For MySQL 8:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('stackoverflow','(.{5})(.*)','$2$1');
-- "overflowstack"
```

You can create capture groups with `()`, and you can refer to them using `$1`, `$2`, etc.

For MariaDB, capturing is done in [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/) with `\\1`, `\\2`, etc. respectively.

Comment: For me this isn't work as expected in 8.0.19 - suspect there may be bugs. (Also seems odd that it doesn't seem to be mentioned in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html).)

Comment: Thanks very much, this resolved my complex/specific data extraction issue. I needed to extract emails from a convoluted 'Text' type column (that had too much unwanted HTML mark up in it), all I did to extract the email-address from it is:  SELECT REGEXP_Replace(description,'(.*mailto:)(.+)(">.*)', '$2') AS `Email` FROM tblBigMarkup;

Comment: In MariaDB it's `\1` instead of `$1`.  "The replace string can have backreferences to the subexpressions in the form \N, where N is a number from 1 to 9." (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/)

Comment: "top search result"... for what?

Comment: Referencing capture groups is not (currently) mentioned in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html), but they do state that "MySQL implements regular expression support using International Components for Unicode (ICU)," which allows [referencing capture-group text](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html#find-and-replace) in regex substitutions.

Comment: Worked awesome for me on MySQL Ver 8.0.22. Thanks!

Comment: +1 this isn't discussed in the documentation for MySQL 8.0.26. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by nesting the function calls in your query. Say you have this string in your column:

`'100 SOME ST,THE VILLAGES,FL 32163,USA'`

and you want to capture the city name. A Capture Group like this would work if MySQL supported it (but it doesn't):

`'^[0-9A-Z\s]+,\s*([a-zA-Z\s]*)'`

You CAN nest function calls to strip off the part you don't want, and then grab the part you DO want like this:

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '^[0-9\\sA-Z]+,', ''), '^[0-9\\sA-Z]+') FROM table_name;`

THE VILLAGES

...

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but it came up in my search and I found an answer.  You can use Rlike with backreferences.  Tested on MySQL 5.7

```
#replace 'aa' with column name
SELECT 'aa' RLIKE '^(.)\1$';
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today and found the this thread, but could not find a satisfying solution. There is no good way to do this in MySQL as far as I can tell.
However, you can hack this together by being a little creative with your regex.

Instead of writing let's say we want to capture "to" inside phrases like "something to capture". The way to do this with capture groups is `something (.*) capture`, but we can similarly use lookback and lookforward to have the initial match be exactly what we want: `(?<=something\s).*(?=\scapture)`.

In your example, this means our regex would become `(?<=^test).(?=\1$)`, which would only match the wildcard.