# Same character 3 times condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I want a query (in msyql) to get records with same character 3 times:

```
aa => false
aaa => true
baaa => true
aaab => true
aaaaaab => true
baaab => true
babababa => false
```

For any character, not only 'a' and 'b'.

The following sentence doesn't work:

```
SELECT field1
FROM mytable
WHERE field1 REGEXP '(.)\1\1';
```

Comment: Possible related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058209/reference-to-groups-in-a-mysql-regex

Comment: @unutbu, given Even's answer definitely not a duplicate of **that** question.

Comment: @Johan: I've tested Evan's answer. I don't believe it works. Also, The [MySQL documentation for REGEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)  never mentions the word "group"...

Comment: @unutbu, I'm confused, what about `To be more precise, a{n} matches exactly n instances of a. a{n,} matches n or more instances of a. a{m,n} matches m through n instances of a, inclusive.` **Quoted from your link**

Comment: @Johan, its the ability to refer to groups with `\1` that is missing. `(.){3,}` does not work because this matches any 3 or more characters. We need them all to be the same character. That requires the `\1` which is missing from MySQL regex syntax.

Comment: @unutbu, crystal clear thanks...

Comment: You can't do that with MySQL since it doesn't support backreferences. And thank Cthulhu for that, because if it did it would open a whole can of worms. Imagine the performance such a query would have on a fairly large table.

Answer (score 3):

May be this can help you.

```
select * from test1 where name REGEXP  '[a]{3}|[b]{3}|[c]{3}|[d]{3}|[e]{3}|[f]{3}|[g]{3}|[h]{3}|[i]{3}|[j]{3}|[k]{3}|[l]{3}|[m]{3}|[n]{3}|[o]{3}|[p]{3}|[q]{3}|[r]{3}|[s]{3}|[t]{3}|[u]{3}|[v]{3}|[w]{3}|[x]{3}|[y]{3}|[z]{3}';
```

It returns records for 3 same and consecutive letters.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the limitation of regular expressions in MySQL, I don't think there's a *simple* way of doing this entirely in the database. Maybe it would be easier to do it as a post-processing step. Here's a suggestion using `sed` on the command line:

```
mysql -BN {connection parameters and query} | sed -n '/\(.\)\1\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you were looking for, but I had fun with it anyway. Polish off my function building skills.

```
drop function if exists char_repeats;
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION char_repeats(string varchar(255), repeat_count int)
    RETURNS int DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE pos int;
    DECLARE len int;
    DECLARE last_char CHAR(1);
    DECLARE cnt int;
    DECLARE ch CHAR(1);

    SET pos = 0;
    SET cnt = 1;
    SET last_char='\0';
    SET len = length(string);


    REPEAT
        SET ch = substring(string, pos, 1);
        IF last_char = ch THEN
           SET cnt = cnt + 1;
        ELSE
           SET cnt = 1;
           SET last_char = ch;
        END IF;

        SET pos = pos + 1;
    UNTIL pos = len OR cnt = repeat_count
    END REPEAT;
    RETURN cnt = repeat_count;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

It's not *that* slow - I ran it across a ~270,000 record database against a field with an average length of 17 characters in 25 seconds (on my local MBP).