# Find non-consecutive repeating text in a mysql column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, email

I have a database with a large set of email addresses.

Because of a bug in a script, the database is full of wrong email addresses. These addresses has a known pattern.

They are made of a true email address, concatenated with a string in the beginning.
This string is itself a part of the email address.

Example:

The correct email should be:

```
john.doe@example.com
```

Instead I have:

```
doejohn.doe@example.com
```

Or also:

```
johndoejohn.doe@example.com
```

How can I identify these addresses?

I thought about creating a regexp that finds repeating text inside a string, but I could find out how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a possibility of name like `barackhusseinobama.obama@example.com`? In this case also does the `first_name` and `last_name` flipped or repeating?

Comment: Also what should be starting point to find the first or last name? Or do you have correct email address now to compare it with incorrect result?

Comment: @Utsav 80% of them are simply `LASTNAMEfirstname.lastname@something.com` , so it would be ok simply to find out emails with the `LASTNAME` part repeating. I don't have the correct email addresses for most of them...

Comment: The more specific you can be of how the repetition is structured, the better the solution can be. Still, it looks like any solution will only be a heuristic as there may be valid addresses containing this kind of repetition.

Comment: @Norman An heuristic is acceptable, I don't need a 100% working search pattern, I just want to clean up a bit that database. The most common pattern is this one (and it would be just ok to match it) `lastnamefirstname.lastname@something.com`, where `lastname` is the repeating part. We can assume that `lastname` is longer than 5 characters.

Comment: Is there always a dot before `lastname`? It could somewhat help us to construct the regex.

Comment: @Timekiller not always, but in many cases. It's ok to match the dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below query to take care of `LASTNAMEfirstname.lastname@something.com` pattern, This will first find the last_name and then replace that with null in the first part before first `.`.

```
concat(replace(substr(email,1,locate('.',email)),substr(email,LOCATE('.',email)+1,locate('@',email)-LOCATE('.',email)-1),'')
   ,
   substr(email,locate('.',email)+1,length(email))
   )
```

**See SQL Fiddle example here**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24fba/2

But this will not take care of `FIRSTNAMElastnameFIRSTNAME.lastname@example.com` pattern.

Comment: +1 because it works ok. A few false positives like `francis.f@example.com`. To select matched results I used: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE mail <>
concat(replace(substr(mail,1,locate('.',mail)),substr(mail,LOCATE('.',mail)+1,locate('@',mail)-LOCATE('.',mail)-1),''),substr(mail,locate('.',mail)+1,length(mail)))`

Answer (score 1):

Can't test right now but this might work:

`^([^@]{5,})[^@]{1,}\.\1@[^@]+$`

Comment: It would work, but Mysql doesn't support backreferences, unfortunately. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058209/

Comment: +1 Because I can just `SELECT * FROM table` and then apply this regexp in ruby. Not very fast, but works better than Utasav solution.