# Regex to get duplicate character in a word

Tags: mysql, regex

Want a regex to find duplicate chracters in a word, which i need to use in **MYSQL**.

I have tried `/([a-zA-Z])\1/` But this returns only if it has continuous occurance. Also tried many more regex.

**Example**::

```
fizz
zoos
java
lava
exec
epee
```

These words should be matched with regex

**But**

```
jamb
chez
some
late
```

These should not.

Any reference will be helpfull.

Please Note: *This question in not a dublicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058209/reference-to-groups-in-a-mysql-regex), because that deals with grouping but I want to get all the duplicate character. Moreover the answer give there say "**Not Possible**" but @tim-biegeleisen has give me a correct solution in my question.*

Comment: MySQL regex does not support in-pattern backreferences.

Comment: Actually i have tried that in PHP for testing purpose. If success then i would add it to mysql

Comment: What do you mean? PHP regex used in `preg_` functions is PCRE, and MySQL uses quite a different regex flavor.

Comment: I need it in MYSQL

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So it's not possible using regex?

Comment: It is not possible with MySQL regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with ugly bloated queries, then you *can* use MySQL's `REGEXP` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE word REGEXP 'a.*a|b.*b|c.*c|d.*d|e.*e|f.*f|g.*g|h.*h|i.*i|j.*j|k.*k|l.*l|m.*m|n.*n|o.*o|p.*p|q.*q|r.*r|s.*s|t.*t|u.*u|v.*v|w.*w|x.*x|y.*y|z.*z';
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's working fine. But is there any way to do it anither way using regex. Because i need to add it A,B,C ....  as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, as @Wiktor mentioned above, MySQL's regex capability is limited.  The nice way to solve this using regex would be to use a backreference check against each character, but MySQL does not support this.

Comment: Your options include handling this in PHP, creating a user defined function in MySQL, or extending my answer (and possibly other things too).

Comment: MariaDB's regexp is more full-featured.