# MySQL Fulltext search: Using distance with wildcards

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, wildcard, distance

My data looks like this:

```
[column "content"]
The quick red horse jumps over the quick dog
The quick brown horse
The quick brown horse jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown horses jumps over the dog
quick as a mouse was the spider. The horse is brown.
```

I use MATCH and AGAINST to get all rows with horse and horses. So, I know, the wildcard* works in BOOLEAN MODE.

```
SELECT * FROM news
WHERE   (MATCH (content) AGAINST ('+quick +horse*' IN BOOLEAN MODE));
```

With the next query I get all rows with "horses" (plural) and "quick", having a distance by a maximum of 3.

```
SELECT * FROM news
WHERE   (MATCH (content) AGAINST  ('"quick horses" @3' IN BOOLEAN MODE));
```

The is to combine both together: all horse or horses AND and "quick", having a distance by a maximum of 3.

```
SELECT * FROM news
WHERE   (MATCH (content) AGAINST  ('"quick horse*" @3' IN BOOLEAN MODE));
```

In the result set only rows included with "horse". "horses" not included!

Full documentation see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/033e02/6

Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: Maybe you can use REGEXP. I already found instructions on how to design "Emulating -near- with a Regular Expression", but I can not get it to work ...
https://www.regular-expressions.info/near.html

`AGAINST ('REGEXP quick+(\W+){0,3)+horse' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`;

Comment: This is a bug in 5.6.23, 5.6.29, 5.7.11. "Bug #80723
@ Distance operator does not bring expected results when used in with wildcards". 
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discovering that it was a documented BUG in MySQL, I searched for another way. Bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80723

Idea: RegEx.
Again, a rocky road, because MySQL currently supports only a part of the common expressions.

[Reference to groups in a MySQL regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058209/reference-to-groups-in-a-mysql-regex)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html

After many experiments this works for me.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7007ac7/1

```
SELECT * FROM news
WHERE content REGEXP 'quick([[:space:][:punct:]])*(((([[:alnum:]])*)*[[:space:][:punct:]]){1,3})horse';
```