# regexp mysql group

Tags: mysql, regex, regexp-substr

I try get **name of city's** from string '{"travelzoo_hotel_name":"Graduate **Minneapolis**","travelzoo_hotel_id":"223","city":"Minneapolis","country":"USA","sales_manager":"Stephen Conti"}'
I try this regexp:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('{\"travelzoo_hotel_name\":\"Graduate Minneapolis\",\"travelzoo_hotel_id\":\"223\",\"city\":\"Minneapolis\",\"country\":\"USA\",\"sales_manager\":\"Stephen Conti\"}'
,'(?:.city...)([[:alnum:]]+)');
```

I have: `'"city":"Minneapolis'`
Me need only name of city:`Minneapolis`.
How to use groups in queries?

[My example in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gmeKHs/1/)
Help me Please

Comment: I think you may use `'(?<="city":")[^"]+'`

Comment: I'ts not possible to reference to a group in mysql  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058209/reference-to-groups-in-a-mysql-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058209/reference-to-groups-in-a-mysql-regex)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference to groups in a MySQL regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058209/reference-to-groups-in-a-mysql-regex)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew mysql regex does not support lookaheads

Comment: @LaurentMouchart It depends which version. [MySQL 8.0 supports more than lookaheads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [MySQL 8.x that uses ICU regex expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html).

It looks like the string you want to process is JSON. You may use [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-paths) with [`JSON_UNQUOTE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote) and a `'$.city'` as JSON path then:

```
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT('{"travelzoo_hotel_name":"Graduate Minneapolis","travelzoo_hotel_id":"223","city":"Minneapolis","country":"USA","sales_manager":"Stephen Conti"}', '$.city'))
```

will return `Minneapolis`.

In your regex, the non-capturing group pattern is still matched and appended to the match value. "Non-capturing" only means no separate memory buffer is alotted to the text captured with a grouping construct. So, you may fix it with `'(?<="city":")[^"]+'` pattern where `(?<="city":")` is a positive lookbehind that matches `"city":"` but does not put it into the match value. The only text you will have in the output is the one matched with `[^"]+`, 1+ chars other than `"`.

Comment: JSON_EXTRACT returned "Minneapolis", it's not valid. Thx for regular, it's work

Comment: @ВовчикНиколаенко You can use `JSON_UNQUOTE`. I updated the answer. Note that you should really consider using JSON parser to handle JSON data.