# MySQL - If cell = certain integer refer to string in another cell

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I have two columns 'Position' and 'PrizeMoneyBreakDown'.

Example of data from Position:

```
3
```

Example of data from PrizeMoneyBreakDown:

```
1st,5285;2nd,1680;3rd,885;4th,550;5th,350;6th,350;7th,350;8th,350;total_value,10000;welfare_fund,200;trophy_total_value,150;
```

I would like to create a new column that stores the prize money won by a horse based on its finishing position.

Example of new cell based on previous example:

```
885
```

I have the code to fetch the stringss, I just need to know how to refer to the 'Position' column create a new column to store the data.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(PrizeMoneyBreakDown, '[0-9]+', 1, 2)
REGEXP_SUBSTR(PrizeMoneyBreakDown, '[0-9]+', 1, 4) 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(PrizeMoneyBreakDown, '[0-9]+', 1, 6)
```

Comment: I don't know that MySQL can capture groups with its REGEX. I thought there might be [something here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058209/reference-to-groups-in-a-mysql-regex) (see both answers), but apparently not. However, though wordy, you could use what you have in a way for the columns: col1 = regex1, col2 = regex2, etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PrizeMoneyBreakDown, ';', Position), ',', -1)
FROM ...
...;
```